# External harddrive not showing proper partition table when removed from external case

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a 2.5TB WD external hdd. I was trying to copy some large files to it and thought I would temporarily shuck it so as to remove the usb 2.0 bottle neck. However when I plug it in directly via SATA the partition table changes drastically. What is going on here?

First photo is hooked up with usb and the second is via SATA

[image: When hooked up via usb]

[image: When hooked up via sata]

Comment: This is to be expected.  The USB-to-SATA controller is likely doing a sector size conversion, which is very common with devices like the WD external drivers, such a conversion increases the compatability of the drive.

Comment: Was the drive formatted with the WD tools?  If so, they offer a different formatting scheme very often, so part of it depends on their tools.

Comment: AFAIK the drive was pulled out of the box and plugged in. The drive is just under 6 years old. While I was here at the time we had another IT guy who set it up.

Comment: I'd definitely agree with @Ramhound on this. You should know that external enclosures with big HDDs (above 2 TB) are often configured with different LBAs (4KB). When you remove the HDD from the enclosure and plug it via SATA, you basically expose the drive to its native 512e LBAs. This would require you to backup the data from the drive while in the enclosure, and reformat it through Disk Management when you connect it via SATA. Hope this helps. Let us know if you have more questions! :)